# Spring Kafka discard message by condition in listener

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In  my Spring Boot/Kafka project I have the following listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.update}", containerFactory = "updateKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
public void onUpdateReceived(ConsumerRecord<String, Update> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment ack) {

    // do some logic

    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

Inside of the listener I need to check some condition according to my business logic and if it is not met  - skip processing of this certain message and let Kafka know to redeliver this message one more time.

The reason I need this - according to the business logic of my application I need to avoid sending more than one post per second into the particular Telegram chat. This why I'd like to check the chatLastSent time in the Kafka listener and postpone message sending if needed(via message redelivery to this Kafka topic)

How to properly do it? Do I only need to not perform the `ack.acknowledge();` this time or there is another, more proper way in order to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_seek_to_current_container_error_handlers).

When you throw an exception, the container will invoke the error handler which will re-seek the unprocessed messages so they will be fetched again on the next poll.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RecordFilterStrategy.

See doc here : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_filtering_messages

Comment: I have added `factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(consumerRecord -> {return false;});` Will the message be redelivered into the topic one more time ? And if no, how to properly configure RecordFilterStrategy to redeliver some messages one more time(based on the condition inside filter method)

Comment: In order to **not process** a message, the filter must return **true** for this message.
I don't think that it is possible to configure a new message delivery if the message has been filtered.

Comment: Well, I'll place `return true`. Will the message be redelivered into the topic one more time?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I'll use this functionality for message filtering, thanks for telling me about this approach but unfortunately, this does not match the requirements I have described in my question.

Comment: There is also a retry capability. If you want to retry some message consuming, you can throw an exception during its processing. 
See : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.0.5.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_retrying_deliveries

Comment: This is actually my question  - is it enough to simply not call `ack.acknowledge();` inside of my listener or do I need to perform some additional actions in order to achieve the message redelivering?

Comment: You can have a look to this post : https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/575